# What is the best counter to a Cynabal?

Tags: eve-online

The cynabal is notoriously known for being a frigate killer.

I personally favor Interceptors (Ares) and Assault Frigates (Ishkur) for PvP, so once a Cynabal shows up, I am dead. The chance for that ship to show up in low- or nullsec is quite high, therefore I always end up losing my ship very early. Because of that, I want to train into another ship that can prolong my ventures into those dangerous areas.

Which ship class or specific ship which is also capable of solo pvp is the best counter to a cynabal? Of course BC can kill it, but I am looking for the smallest ship size possible to deal with it.

*If possible please stick with Gallente or Minmatar Ships in your answer*

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't talk about specific ships so much, mostly general tactics, but this is still a good article about taking on pirate cruisers :

http://www.evealtruist.com/2011/11/know-your-enemy-pirate-cruisers.html

I believe it's still valid advice at the moment, but it may not be when the pirate cruisers get rebalanced in an upcoming patch.